# component-wise product of a sparse vector with a component-wise function of another vector in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have two vectors `b` and `a`. The components of the latter (`a`) are almost always zero except a few.

If I want to compute component-wise product of a and a component-wise function (such as exp) of b, I can do

```
a*exp(b)
```

However for those majority zero components of a, the evaluation of exp on the corresponding components of b will be a waste.

I was wondering under cases such as this one, is it possible to program more efficiently in R? Or there is no need to change. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on DWin's answer, and your comment to it, just keep track of the `0` and add back in the trivial answers:

```
## Dummy data
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
b <- runif(100)

## something to hold results
out <- numeric(length(a))
## the computations you *want* to do
want <- !a==0
## fill in the wanted answers
out[want] <- a[want] * exp(b[want])
```

Which gives the correct results:

```
> all.equal(out, a * exp(b))
[1] TRUE
```

If you wanted, you could wrap this into a function:

```
myFun <- function(a, b) {
    out <- numeric(length(a))
    want <- !a==0
    out[want] <- a[want] * exp(b[want])
    return(out)
}
```

Then use it

```
> all.equal(out, myFun(a, b))
[1] TRUE
```

**But** none of this is more efficient than using `a * exp(b)` directly. Both `*` and `exp()` are vectorised so will run very quickly, much more quickly than any of the booking keeping measures used in the various answers so far.

Whether you need the book-keeping solutions will depend on how expensive your function (`exp()` in the example in your Q) is in compute terms. Try both approaches on a small sample and evaluate the timings (using `system.time()`) to see if it is worth the extra effort of doing the subsetting to track the 0.

Comment: -1 for treating b as zero.  +1 for note on runtime efficiency.  sum = 0.

Comment: I can't upvote you now, after fiddling with the vote buttons before.  Make a tiny edit and then I can.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your expression with:

```
ifelse(a==0,0,a*exp(b))
```

I'd be surprised if this made a performance improvement, though, since R is interpreted, the overhead of running the `ifelse` is probably worse than wasting the `exp` invocation.

Comment: That needs to be `ifelse(b == 0, a, a*exp(b))` --- noting that it is `b` that contains the 0's and that if `b` *is* zero, then we have `a * 1` so we need to return `a` not `0` for those cases.

Comment: Check the question - "However for those majority zero components of a, the evaluation of exp on the corresponding components of b will be a waste."

Comment: Sorry, you are totally correct! Several of us seem to have misread that!

Comment: The only problem with your answer (and the rest of ours, but to a lesser extent) is that they are **all** slower than evaluating `a * exp(b)`. There is too much overhead in `ifelse()` and the other alternatives to justify using them for cases such as this.

Comment: See the last paragraph of my question!

Comment: So I need more coffee - obviously not awake yet! Although in my defence, you added that to your answer after I'd read it but was editing my own answer to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to DWin's suggestion:

```
> n <- 1e5
> nonzero <- .01
> b <- rnorm(n)
> a <- rep(0, n)
> a[1:(n*nonzero)] <- rnorm(n*nonzero)
> 
> system.time(replicate(100, {
+                   c <- a*exp(b)
+               }))
   user      system     elapsed 
   1.19        0.05        1.23 
> system.time(replicate(100, {
+                   zero <- a < .Machine$double.eps
+                   c <- a
+                   c[!zero] <- a[!zero]*exp(b[!zero])
+               }))
   user      system     elapsed 
   0.42        0.08        0.50
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish that by indexing both vectors with a test for whatever situation you deem a waste. If the function is more time costly than exp, it might make a difference:

```
a[ !b==0 ]*exp( b[!b==0] )
```

Also recognize that there are traps to testing for equality with numeric mode. You may want to look at zapsmall and all.equal as alternatives depending on what the real problem is.

```
> 3/10 == 0.1*3
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks DWin! But a[ !b==0 ]*exp( b[!b==0] ) will give different result from a*exp(b).

Comment: Yep. Neuronal crosstalk. Should have been a[ !a==0 ]*exp( b[!a==0] ) but then still suffers from not providing the full vector.